# Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'. in android studio flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, groovy, gradlew

I'm trying to run a Flutter project through Android Studio, but I'm getting this error. What's the problem?

this is the error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':gradle:detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:?.?.??.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried all the solutions available on the internet, but to no avail.

what should I do?

Comment: Is the project available anywhere? What are you running? Does the error really contain all those question marks instead of a version? Questions like this without something we can run to show what you're seeing always end up as guesswork

Comment: Are there _really_ `?.?.??` in the output? Could it be, that the template you are using actually added those to make you pick a proper number? Note that only versions 2 and 3 are under the `org.codehaus` group - newer versions are under `.org.apache`.

Answer (score 0):

If the language of your system is Arabic, try to change it to English, then restarting your system and open the project again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).